# Free category generated from a graph

Tags: category-theory

I have the following graph

[image]

where $de = 1 = ce$, $dp = cq$, $dm = dq$, and $cm = cp$.

I would like to generate the free category from this graph. Its objects will be $0$, $1$, $2$. The definition says that its morphisms will be tuples of composable arrows. But I do not quite understand what it means.

Can $(e,d,e,c)$ be a morphism which I believe is a tuple of composable arrows?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have isn't a graph. $de=ce$ is an equation in a category, not in a graph. What we should do is first generate the free category and then apply your relations. That said, your proposed morphism indeed is one in the free category.

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing your wisdom

Comment: @James I'm glad it helped.